# Bigquery Stream: Missing data after new table created

Tags: google-bigquery

We recently noticed that within a short period of time after a new table being created, data which were streamed in, without any exceptions or errors, just got missing.  Is there any known grace time the streaming should wait?

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'warm up' time of a few seconds after streaming first occurs on a table before it is available for querying. There is a similar warm up time if you stop streaming to the table for more than 24 hours and then start again.

See the docs here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#dataavailability

Comment: I'm aware of this warm-up time for data to be 'visible'. But by 'missing data', I mean those data does not exist in BQ table.

Comment: You're saying that the data never becomes available?

Comment: Yeah, they never becomes available. But I think I found the answer, except one little issue I cannot understand. Please refer to my answer. Thank you Jordan

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured out what happened by printing out trace info step by step. The multi-thread contributed to cover up the issue for a long time.

This the original 'missing data' code to create a table:

```
insert = sBIGQUERY.tables().insert(mProjectId, mDataset, table);
logger.info("Table " + tid.toString()+" is created at " + new Date(insert
                .execute().getCreationTime()));
```

where insert.execute().getCreationTime() never returned.... (I don't know why) and thus the rest of my process(put data back to the sending queue to wait for next stream) didn't execute.

After I change it to:

```
sBIGQUERY.tables().insert(mProjectId, mDataset, table).execute();
logger.info("Table " + tid.toString()+" is created");
```

It runs properly and we get all the data up to BQ.

@Jordan Tigani, do you know the reason for getCreationTime() never get back? (or during quite a long period than I can wait for)

Comment: My assumption is that the call that got stuck is execute() rather than getCreationTime() (the insert doesn't happen until you run execute()... it doesn't happen immediately after you call insert(). You mentioned using multi-threading. Are you using a new HTTP object in each thread? If not, you'll have problems.

Comment: but it doesn't make sense that when I separate execute() with getCreationTime() then it goes fine. What is the new HTTP object you mentioned?

Comment: sBIGQUERY = new Bigquery.Builder(transport, ConfigConstants.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName("BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1").setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();  this is all I have to make a BQ request call. where should I put the http object?

Comment: Ack ... I didn't realize that you're using python instead of java. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: That said, getCreationTime() should never block. It just reads data that is already in memory. Consider adding timeouts as specified here: https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/HandlingTimeoutsAndErrors